# MATLAB Concatenating struct: Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent

Tags: matlab

I am facing this error when running the below code:

> Error using datetime/horzcat (line 1292) Dimensions of arrays being
>   concatenated are not consistent.

I have checked and with each iteration, the number of columns is the same. I believe this is because a column is in datetime format. The best practice of working with datetime columns in Matlab is to first convert it to string type?

```
% Initialize an empty struct
fields = {'time','activity'};
c = cell(length(fields),1);
timetable = cell2struct(c,fields);


% Loop to concatenate struct
for i=1:4
   T.time = *a datetime array. format: 1000 * 1 datetime*
   T.activity = *an array of strings. format: 1000 * 1 cell*
   timetable.time = [timetable.time, T.time];
   timetable.activity = [timetable.activity, T.activity];
end
```

Sample of T.time (in datetime format):

```
["27-Aug-2018 08:00:00", "27-Aug-2018 08:00:01", "27-Aug-2018 08:00:02"]
```

Sample of T.activity (strings in a cell):

```
["dinner", "dinner", "dinner"]
```

Comment: Did you consider initializing your struct values with an empty cell array? timetable = cell2struct(c,fields);

    timetable.time = {};
    timetable.activity = {};

Comment: Please provide an example that reproduces the issue. Your example code functions fine.